# web application interface gathers inputs for background application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am in the process of creating a web application interface that is is basically a search engine but runs long in depth searches. I have the search processes working well in a desktop version and would basically want the web app to accept new search jobs with the parameters and feed it to the search process which will run as a background process. The web app will allow for multiple searches. This should be easy but I am not sure how to pass the parameters using a background thread or parallel task to call the processing classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table in a database for adding new items to the queue. Have main process check that table for new transactions to add to is main queue.

Comment: do you mean the new items being the parameters for the searches?

Comment: yah, and your thread or application that is running already, has a routine to check the table for new transactions to process. I was imagining the table could be updatable from any interface allowing you to use a separate process/machine/platform to inject new parameters.